# /bin/sh: 1: fabric: Permission denied when commit some changes to local repo

Tags: linux, git, terminal

Today when I commit some git changes to local repo like this in GitHub Codespaces terminal:

```
git commit -m "feat: enable the editor pick button"
```

shows error like this:

```
@jiangxiaoqiang ➜ /workspaces/react-admin (umi) $ git commit -m "feat: enable the editor pick button"
.git/hooks/pre-commit: 9: [: pre-commit: unexpected operator
.git/hooks/prepare-commit-msg: 9: [: prepare-commit-msg: unexpected operator
.git/hooks/commit-msg: 9: [: commit-msg: unexpected operator
 > running commit-msg hook: fabric verify-commit
/bin/sh: 1: fabric: Permission denied

commit-msg hook failed (add --no-verify to bypass)
```

why did this happen? what should I do to avoid this problem? this is hte `commit-msg` hooks:

```
@jiangxiaoqiang ➜ /workspaces/react-admin/.git/hooks (umi) $ cat commit-msg
#!/bin/sh
#yorkie 2.0.5

command_exists () {
  command -v "$1" >/dev/null 2>&1
}

has_hook_script () {
  if [ $1 == 'pre-commit' ];then 
    return 0 
  fi
  [ -f package.json ] && cat package.json | grep -q "\"$1\"[[:space:]]*:"
}

# OS X and Linux only
load_nvm () {
  # If nvm is not loaded, load it
  command_exists nvm || {
    export NVM_DIR="$1"
    [ -s "$1/nvm.sh" ] && . "$1/nvm.sh"
  }
}

# OS X and Linux only
run_nvm () {
  # If nvm has been loaded correctly, use project .nvmrc
  command_exists nvm && [ -f .nvmrc ] && nvm use
}

cd "."

# Check if commit-msg is defined, skip if not
has_hook_script commit-msg || exit 0

# Add common path where Node can be found
# Brew standard installation path /usr/local/bin
# Node standard installation path /usr/local
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local"

# Try to load nvm using path of standard installation
load_nvm /home/codespace/.nvm
run_nvm

# Export Git hook params
export GIT_PARAMS="$*"

# Run hook
node "./node_modules/@umijs/yorkie/src/runner.js" commit-msg || {
  echo
  echo "commit-msg hook failed (add --no-verify to bypass)"
  exit 1
}
```

Comment: as the error messages say, you have bunch of broken hooks installed in your repo, and `fabric` has a wrong permission, whatever `fabric` is. Since we don't know your hooks, we don't know what your `fabric` is, and you don't show any debugging attempts into these, we really can't help :(

Comment: I have pasted the hook.@MarcusMüller